# Add value to input on radio click, and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a donate form where one of the options needs to be populated with a certain amount because its a fixed price point. I found and ran code that works fine to populate the input with the selection of a radio input, but I'd like it to be toggled in a way in that if I select another option, the populated amount will be removed. Is that possible?

Here is what I have working now:

```js
$('input#yearCaring').on('change', function() {
  $('input[name="Amount"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="In Honor/Memory Of" value="No" />
  <label>No Thanks</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="In Honor/Memory Of" id="yearCaring" value="100" />
  <label>Year of Caring</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="In Honor/Memory Of" value="In Memory" />
  <label>In Memory</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="In Memory Note" style="display: none;" value="" />
  <input type="radio" name="In Honor/Memory Of" value="In Celebration" />
  <label>In Celebration</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="In Celebration Note" style="display: none;" value="" />
</div>

<label>Amount (Canadian Dollars):</label>
<input type="text" name="Amount" required="" value="" />
```

How would I go about 'toggling' it?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/immediateahughes/y9kbqy75/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check all the radio buttons and only apply the value if it matches a certain ID like so:

```js
$('input:radio').change(function () {
    $('input[name="Amount"]').val( (this.id == 'yearCaring') ? this.value : '').prop('disabled',(this.id == 'yearCaring') ? true : false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div>
        <input name="In Honor/Memory Of" type="radio" value="No" />
        <label>No Thanks</label>
        <br />
        <input name="In Honor/Memory Of" id="yearCaring" type="radio" value="100" />
        <label>Year of Caring</label>
        <br />
        <input name="In Honor/Memory Of" type="radio" value="In Memory" />
        <label>In Memory</label>
        <br />
        <input name="In Memory Note" style="display: none;" type="text" value="" />
        <input name="In Honor/Memory Of" type="radio" value="In Celebration" />
        <label>In Celebration</label>
        <br />
        <input name="In Celebration Note" style="display: none;" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <label>Amount (Canadian Dollars):</label>
    <input name="Amount" required="" type="text" value="" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can disable the input box while it's populated with the radio value? I added .attr('disabled','disabled') but it  didn't work properly

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
$('input[name="In Honor/Memory Of"]').on('change', function() {
        $('input[name="Amount"]').val($(this).val());
});
```